# how to save listbox item to multiple database Fields? like split

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

i'm using Listbox1 and listbox2 now i want to transfer the selected items from listbox1 to listbox2 which are (ID, firstname middlename lastname) so in my database firstname and middlename and lastname are in separate fields so after i trasnfer my listbox1 items to listbox2 i want to save it to database but the problem is ... i don't know how to split those words and give each words a string name to command them to save to their assigned fields

here's my code for sqlconnection

```
void database1()
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From [User_TBL_DB]", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        DataTable myDataTable = ds.Tables[0];
        DataRow tempRow = null;

        foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            tempRow = tempRow_Variable;
            ListBox2.Items.Add((tempRow["ID"] + ", " + tempRow["Firstname"] + " " + " " + tempRow["Middlename"] + " " + " " + tempRow["Lastname"]));
        }
    }
```

then this is how i transfer the items from listbox1 to listbox2

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                ListBox3.Items.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
                ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }


        }
    }
```

now for saving.. i don't know..

and after i transfer the item to listbox2 from listbox1 the item will be deleted to the database of listbox1 after saving ..

listbox1 database name is

```
 [User_TBL_DB] 
fields: ID,Firstname,Middlename,lastname
```

listbox2 database name is

```
[CopyUser_TBL_DB] 
fields: ID,Firstname,Middlename,lastname
```

here's the current output

[image]

Comment: There should be logic to split.But there isn't any to determine First and Last names. You can split strings using split function and split using ' ' space. You can take 1st one as number, From second to Last as name. But how can you determine betwn 1st and last names?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to split words and add them to db, then do like

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            ListBox3.Items.Add(ListBox2.Items[i]);
            string[] splits = ListBox2.Items[i].ToString().Split(new char[]{' ', ','}); // For splitting both empty space and comma (you've used in ur question)
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [CopyUser_TBL_DB] ([ID], [Firstname], [Middlename], [Lastname]) Values (@ID, @FName, @MName, @LName)", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(splits[0]);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = splits[1];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = splits[2];
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = splits[3];
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This fails if someone enter a space in the first name, and is not a good approach..

.

.

**A good approach is to create a class and store details in it.**

```
class UserDetails
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FullRowDisplay { get; set; }

        public UserDetails(string id, string fName, string mName, string lName)
        {
            ID = id;
            FirstName = fName;
            MiddleName = mName;
            LastName = lName;
            FullRowDisplay = id + " " + fName + " " + mName + " " + lName;
        }

    }
```

and in the reading side

```
ListBox1.DisplayMember = ListBox2.DisplayMember = "FullRowDisplay";
foreach (DataRow tempRow_Variable in myDataTable.Rows)
    {
        tempRow = tempRow_Variable;
        ListBox2.Items.Add(new UserDetails(tempRow["ID"], tempRow["Firstname"], tempRow["Middlename"], tempRow["Lastname"]));
    }
```

and at the inserting part

```
if (ListBox2.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        UserDetails udetail = ListBox2.Items[i];
        ListBox3.Items.Add(udetail);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into [CopyUser_TBL_DB] ([ID], [Firstname], [Middlename], [Lastname]) Values (@ID, @FName, @MName, @LName)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(udetail.ID);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = udetail.FirstName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = udetail.MiddleName;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = udetail.LastName;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: and if someone enter a space in the first name all we have to do is to remove the space on the split and replace it ^_^ right?  we can use "-" or "_" or " / " or " | "